# How do you write <p></p> and display it on your site?

Tags: html

How do you write `<p></p>` so that it can be displayed as text in an HTML page, rather than be interpreted as HTML (which would give an empty paragraph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the

in the view,
Because, when you type that inside html element, it may be getting it as the html element itself.

if your purpose is showing that in the view just try this.
&ltp> &lt/p>
Check this snippet :

```html
&ltp> &lt/p>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with using span

```html
<span> < </span> <span>p</span> > <span> < </span> / <span>p</span><span> > </span>
```

or you can do below like this

```html
&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
View the source of this page. It managed it! 

<p><\p>
```

and the answer was `&lt;p&gt;&lt;\p&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

A *P* tag should print out text on your site no matter what. However, on most occasions you will need to refresh (F5) your page in order for it to take effect. Furthermore, if you got anything on your site that could be covering it up, try removing it just to see whether another element is "eating it up" or not. For example, try removing a banner image if thats something you got, or a navbar.

Usage for P, just in case:

```
<p> Text goes here </p>
```

Comment: I think the question is how to display raw html

Comment: @Mike You sure? He afterall asked how to properly display the <p></p> tags. Still, raw html is as easy as just writing it out without anything around it, which I wouldn't recommend but the option is there.

Comment: i wanted to display the p tag on my site. its solved anyways

Comment: Oh!! Now I see what you ment. My bad on that part. Ah well - Glad you got it sorted! @MichaelThin

Answer (score 1):

Use Html entities to display the reserved html symbol

[HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

this is what you mean? sorry if i understand wrongly but your description is very short.