# How can I write HTML tags so they appear as tags on the screen?

Tags: html

I am working with a html project and my task is to discribe html with facts and examples.

How do i write this example so i just get the text on my website?

`<p>`(The text between  and  describes the web page, and the text between  and  is the visible page content. The markup text "This is a title" defines the browser page title.)`</p>`

Comment: I'm not even remotely sure what you're asking, but you can nest html tags.

Comment: This question is really checking a lot off of the "How *not* to ask a question" list. Your question is very unclear, it's too broad, and it shows no attempt at solving it on your own. Furthermore it's an incredibly basic HTML question that you could find the answer to in a matter of seconds, just by doing a simple google search. StackOverflow is a handy resource when you need to understand why *your attempt is not working*, but it is *not* exactly a resource for simple Q&A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you write <p></p> and display it on your site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783303/how-do-you-write-p-p-and-display-it-on-your-site)

Comment: Checkout this answer.
This answer has the way to do it.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37783880/5476757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "entities":  `&lt;`for `<` and `&gt;`for `>`

So a `<p>` tag would be written as `&lt;p&gt;`

Example:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqqObp

Comment: this is the first time i use this website but thanks for the answer